# How to combine ANDs and ORs in the WHERE clause using a Query Object?

Tags: jdatabase, sql

Given the desired SQL below, where Cond1 *and* Cond2 must be met *OR* Cond3 must be met for selection, what is the correct way to use `getQuery()` to achieve it?

**Desired SQL:** *Condition1 and Condition2 within parentheses)*

```
SELECT * FROM #__myTable 
WHERE (condition1=true AND condition2=true) OR condition3=true
```

**With Chaining:**  *specifying OR in the ->where()*

```
$query = $db->getQuery(true);
$query->select('* FROM #__myTable')
->where('condition1 = true AND condition2 = true','OR')
->where('condition3 = true');
```

*Resulting SQL: (SQL is missing parentheses)*

```
SELECT * FROM scm_myTable
WHERE condition1 = true AND condition2 = true OR condition3 = true
```

**With Arrays**  *specifying OR in the ->where()*

```
$query = $db->getQuery(true);
$conditions12 = array(
    'condition1 = true',
    'condition2 = true'
);
$conditions3 = array(
    'condition3 = true'
);
$query->select('* FROM #__myTable')
->where($conditions12, 'OR')
->where($conditions3);
```

*Resulting SQL: (SQL is missing parentheses)*

```
SELECT * FROM scm_myTable
WHERE condition1 = true OR condition2 = true OR condition3 = true
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Including the parentheses that are needed, with Chaining , produced the desired SQL:

**With Chaining:**  *specifying OR and wrapping Cond1/2 in parentheses*

```
$query = $db->getQuery(true);
$query->select('* FROM #__myTable')
->where('(condition1 = true AND condition2 = true)','OR')
->where('condition3 = true');
```

*Resulting SQL: (includes parentheses)*

```
SELECT * FROM scm_myTable
WHERE (condition1 = true AND condition2 = true) OR condition3 = true
```

*OR use orWhere/andWhere*

```
$query = $db->getQyery(true);
$query->select('*')
->from($db->quoteName('#__myTable'))
->where($db-quoteName('condition3') . ' = TRUE')
->orWhere(array($db->quoteName('condition1') . ' = TRUE', $db->quoteName('condition2') . ' = TRUE'));
```